# Refreshing Lakehouse data during a notebook session in Microsoft Fabric

Tags: file, session, pyspark, data-lakehouse, microsoft-fabric

I am running a pyspark script in a notebook in Microsoft Fabric (preview).

The script gets the last modification time of test.csv, which is located in a lakehouse in the same workspace.

The problem is, as soon as you start the session of the notebook, **the data of the lakehouse does not refresh for the script**. So even if you replace test.csv, or even delete it, the script will only know about the test.csv which existed when the session started.

Is there a way to refresh the data during the session, or get access to the real file?

To get the last modification time i am using the following code:

```
last_modification_time = os.stat(file_path).st_mtime
```

i also tried

```
last_modification_time = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
```

Comment: Try using the MSSparkUtils to get the file mod time 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python#file-system-utilities
Something like files = mssparkutils.fs.ls('Files/TestData/nyctaxi_l1000.csv')
for file in files:
    print(file.name, file.isDir, file.isFile, file.path, file.size, file.modifyTime)

Comment: After some testing, it doesn't seem to update the date at all. Raise the issue with an ms support ticket

Comment: Using the mssparkutnils, it also sometimes returns no modify time in the dict it returns., so is a bug